# Query if user has "Cannot change password" checked in Active Directory

Tags: vb.net, ldap, adsi

I'm trying to check this information for an app i'm developing...

I'm trying to query userAccountControl, but I've figured out AD doesn't update this correctly if it's set.

This is how I currently search UserAccountControl

```
 If (res.Properties.Contains("userAccountControl")) Then
            userAccountControl = doespasswordexpire(res.Properties("userAccountControl").Item(0))
            userAccountControlPNR = PasswordNotRequired(res.Properties("userAccountControl").Item(0))
            userAccountControlSCR = SmartCardRequired(res.Properties("userAccountControl").Item(0))
        Else
            userAccountControl = ""
            userAccountControlPNR = ""
            userAccountControlSCR = ""
 End If
```

How would I do this in ADSI or LDAP? I do not want to use PrincipalContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `userAccountControl` attribute to modify, or even query, the "cannot change password" setting. It's listed in the Microsoft's documentation as a possible flag, but it doesn't work (not sure if it was ever intended to?).

To check if that is set you have to parse out the user's ACEs in their DACL. You can get that from the `ntSecurityDescriptor` attribute of the user and programmatically parse it. There's a good starting example of that in [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/e947d590-d183-46b9-9a7a-4e785638c6fb/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-active-directory-user-accounts-where-the-user-cannot-change-the-password?forum=ITCG).

Some additional MSDN info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746398.aspx

Comment: First example is in VBS, so i'm a little confused by it. The MSDN example is a little.... above my head. I've been scowering google for examples, but not finding any that I can understand.

Comment: VB.NET is definitely not my forte, but [this](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1237700) seems to be an example that might help. Follow it through the beginning of the try block up where it lists `' Get the DACL from the security descriptor.`. You then need to iterate the ACEs on the DiscretionaryAcl instance, and check for the specific ACE that controls this, which seems to have an ACE object type GUID of `{AB721A53-1E2F-11D0-9819-00AA0040529B}`.